# does samba, 389 Directory Server, ApacheDS, OpenLDAP support SSO

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm trying to find out which one in the listed bellow support Single Sign On(SSO) by default. If it doesn't support by default, I wonder if there is a solution to add SSO in it?

- Samba
- 389 Directory Server
- ApacheDS
- OpenLDAP

I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those are Active Directories. Active Directory is a Microsoft product. Apache DS and Samba support Kerberos out of the box. The rest requires additional configuration.